# JavaScript FileReader to get data from file

Tags: javascript, html

After browsing around the internet for a few hours to find a solution, I found out a few methods of getting the information from a filereader, but not quite to what I need.

```
function submitfile() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("filesubmission").files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (REvent) {
        document.getElementById("outputcontent").innerHTML = "<iframe width='100%' id='outputdata' scrolling='yes' onload='resizeIframe(this)' src='"+REvent.target.result+"'></iframe>";   
    };
}
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

That is the code that I'm using after a user selects a file, which I allow .html, .htm, .txt, or .xml. The Iframe is then resized to match the content. I have that functionality working, however I need to have a method of replacing text in the iframe with certain values that the user provides in `<input>` tags earlier. An example would be I need to be able to replace "[c1]" in the file the user provides with a client's name, such as "John Smith".

The way I would prefer to do this would be through the content of the file itself, rather than using a source in an iframe or data in an object. If I can get this into the original file itself where it can be edited, that would solve the problem.

I need to be able to do this without the use of jQuery or other plugins, since this is a local file that should be able to work standalone as a tool for my client.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOMParser to parse the reader's result:

```
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(reader.result,"text/html");
```

or any other mime type, 
Then, update the some nodes within the doc based on the inputs you mention.
Then use the iframe's `contentDocument` to adopt the node using `document.adoptNode`. That will return the node with its ownerDocument pointing to the iframe. Lastly append it to the iframe's body.